# Azure APIM Integration with Istio Gateway

Tags: azure, istio, azure-api-management, azure-aks

We are trying to implement Istio Service mesh and trying to use Istio Gateway, we are already using Azure APIM as an ingress gateway, all the traffic has to go through Azure APIM and to Azure Kubernetes.  Can someone guide us or help us out, how to integrate Azure APIM with Istio Gateway.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using Option 2 as mentioned in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-kubernetes). If so, you can install istio ingress controller and use for Azure API management as gateway. I would suggest to disable mTLS option of Azure APIM and use mTLS option as provided by istio (as istio can manage certificates).

If you are facing any difficult doing so, please share it and I will try to help.